# How to mask protected folder path to make it look like it's served from another location?

Tags: nginx

I am using X-Accel to serve protected folder that contains images: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/

Currently I store the files in the `/protected_files` folder. So now in order to see the files using X-Accel, I pass the path containing the `/protected_files` URL, for example `protected_files/image1.jpg`.

This is how I set the protection on the protected folder:

```
location /protected_files {
  internal;
}
```

Then in order to view the files with X-Accel, I pass the path with the `X-Accel-Redirect`.

Is there a way to mask the URL so that it will look like it's being served from another URL?
like `/fake_folder/image1.jpg`?

What I tried, and didn't work was to create another folder with the desired fake name, then add alias to the real name:

```
location /fake_folder {
  internal;
  alias /protected_files;
}
```

Then I pass the URL with `/fake_folder/image1.jpg`, but I get error 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#internal) on internal, rewritten requests count as internal requests. The following should work:

```
location /fake_folder {
    rewrite ^/fake_folder/(.*)$ /protected_files/$1 break;
}
```

Comment: It probably doesn't even need the fake_folder location block.

Comment: thank you, it does seem to work. And yes I did not use the `fake_folder` block in my post, but only yours. Do you think it's possible to do something similar but with `alias` as seen in the example in the docs in the link?